# Complicated Transform of a Beta Random Variable

Tags: distributions, random-variable, beta-distribution, transform

> Consider a Beta distributed random variable, $X \sim Beta(a,b)$ Then consider the transform $$Y = \sqrt{K\frac{X}{1-X}}$$ where $K > 0$ is a constant.

How could you go about finding the PDF of $Y$? Is it a named distribution?

It seems that you cannot apply the transformation formula, since the mapping is not strictly monotonic and doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: $\tfrac{X}{1-X}$ follows [beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution)

Comment: Although you are correct that the mapping *as defined for all real numbers* is not monotonic, that's not relevant.  The chance is zero that $X$ will lie outside the interval $(0,1)$ and on that interval the mapping is well-defined, differentiable, and monotonic, making this a straightforward application of the usual transformation formulas.

Comment: @whuber Am I correct in finding that $Y$ in the general case is distributed as a generalised beta of the second kind?

Comment: That sounds right.  The relationships become evident when you re-express the variables as $X=\sin^2(\Theta),$ for which $Y \propto \tan(\Theta).$